# Element Disappears After Changing Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a custom resize functionality which will allow the user to drag the vertical border between two divs to resize their widths in respect to each other.  I am accomplishing this by creating an invisible third div that has a width of 10px with a resize cursor and sits on top of the border between the two elements.  When the user clicks on the invisible 3rd div and drags it, an event listener changes the width of the left element, then re positions the 3rd div accordingly.

However, I am getting a strange error where the left element in question seems to disappear / get removed after changing the width. I have verified this by doing a `$("#divID").length` to the console before and after.  Before shows a count of 1, after shows a count of 0.  This is causing an error in one of the functions that uses the `$("#divID").offset()` function.

Here is the associated code. The `$("#"+resultsDiv)` is the left side which I referred to previously.

```
/**
 * This will create an invisible div between the results pane (left) and map (right) that will allow the user to click and resize
 */
function handleResize() {
    let e = document.createElement('div');
    setResizeProperties(e);

    document.body.appendChild(e);

    $(e).mousedown(function() {
        $("#"+resultsDiv).mousemove(function(el) {
            doResize(el,$(this));
        });

    }).mouseup(function() {
        $("#"+resultsDiv).unbind("mousemove",doResize);
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setResizeProperties(e);
    });
}

/**
 * Actually change the length
 * @param el to get mouse page X from
 * @param e of the invisible resize handle object
 */
function doResize(el,e) {
    console.log($("#"+resultsDiv).width());
    $("#"+resultsDiv).css("width",(el.pageX - 10 - $("#"+resultsDiv).offset().left));
    console.log($("#"+resultsDiv).width());
    console.log();
    setResizeProperties(e);
}

/**
 * Set the resize properties for the div element
 * @param e of the invisible resize handle obbject
 */
function setResizeProperties(e) {
    $(e).attr("id","resizeHandler");
    //$(e).css("visibility","hidden");
    $(e).css("background-color","red");
    $(e).css("width","20px");
    $(e).css("height",$("#gMapContainer").css("height"));
    $(e).css("cursor","ew-resize");
    $(e).css("position","absolute");

    console.log($("#"+resultsDiv).length);

    $(e).css("left",$("#"+resultsDiv).width() + $("#"+resultsDiv).offset().left);
    $(e).css("top",$("#resultsContainer").offset().top);
    $(e).css("z-index",10000);
}
```

Here is a link to the JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonQDixon/pt70yLbs/

If not already set, it uses the latest version of JQuery.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr/jsfiddle showcasing the code and the html?

Comment: Here is the JS fiddle.  If it isn't set, it uses the latest version of JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonQDixon/ny9L5f8t/8/

Comment: The new JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/BrandonQDixon/pt70yLbs/